# What happened to lowercase-comparisons in Spring Security 3.1?

Tags: spring-security

I recently upgraded to 3.1 from 3.0 and lowercase-comparison is no longer available.

What happened to it and what can I do to ensure case sensitivity when using an ldap server for authentication ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `lowercase-comparisons` was about matching incoming request URLs to defined patterns and was removed because we now have `RequestMatcher` interface which encapsulates that behaviour, and which can be set independently using the namespace, so having both doesn't make sense. Either way I don't see a connection with LDAP authentication.

Comment: The bottom line is is that I couldn't get Spring Security to be case sensitive. I researched the topic and found that other people had asked similar questions and had not been answered.  I was not originally using lowercase-comparison but the documentation i read indicated it is used prior to 3.1 to enable disable case sensitivity. In regards to what you mentioned I remember reading something about that in the 3.1 docs and was confused why lowercase-comparison is used differently now as opposed to the 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way of making sure that case sensitivity is used during the login process.

I added caseExactMatch to the search filter. I have pasted in a portion of my ldap-authentication-provider below to assist other people with same issue.

```
<authentication-manager>
<ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapServer"  
   user-search-base="ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com" 
   user-search-filter="(uid:caseExactMatch:={0})"
   group-role-attribute="cn"
   group-search-base="ou=Groups,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
   group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
   role-prefix="ROLE_"
   user-details-class="inetOrgPerson" 
   />
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Luke, this seems to be the alternative - request-matcher="ciRegex" (in 3.1+) to lowercase-comparisons="true"(3.0). Without which spring is comparing with case sensitivity.